# Single password field for posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to set up a page with a single password input field, which on submit redirects the user to the appropriate post for the given password.

Thought something like this would work:

**Template:**

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="password" name="post_password" value=""/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
    <?php             
            $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id FROM wp_posts WHERE post_password = '{$_POST['post_password']}'");
            if ($result) {
                $location = $result[0]->id;
                do_action('init', $location); 
            } else {
                echo '<p>Invalid password</p>';
            }  

    ?>
```

**Functions.php:**

```
function process_post($arg0){    
    if (isset($arg0) {
        wp_safe_redirect(get_bloginfo('url'). "/?page_id=" . $arg0 );   
        exit();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'process_post', 10, 1);
```

But doesn't work. Thought that using the init hook would avoid the header info sent error, but I'm still getting it.

Still need to actually set the submitted password as the cookie value too - is there a WP function to do that?

Comment: That is not the actual setup in your template right? The php code after the form with no action defined?

Comment: @koala_dev, the action param doesn't have to be defined. If left empty, the form submits to the current url in view.

Comment: @NADH you're right, I'm sorry I wasn't thinking straight, I should go to bed now...

Comment: You should go ahead and post this as a solution and accept it, rather than just editing your original post. This will help direct other people to your solution in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output buffering made all the difference - added that action, plus setting the post password cookie prior to the redirect. The target page is then wrapped in a post_password_required check, and redirects back to the parent page if no password has been set. All sweet, exactly what I was trying to achieve (aside from it not working if you are logged in to Wordpress and try to access a protected post, which for my context doesn't matter).

Functions.php:

```
function process_post($arg0, $arg1){
    if ($arg0 != "") {
        setcookie('wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH, wp_hash_password( $arg1 ), time() + 60, COOKIEPATH);
        wp_safe_redirect(get_bloginfo('url'). "/gallery/" . $arg0 );
        exit;  
    }
}
add_action('init', 'process_post', 10, 2);

function app_output_buffer() {
  ob_start();
}
add_action('init', 'app_output_buffer');
```

Template:

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="password" name="post_password" value=""/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
    <?php             
        if (isset($_POST['post_password']) ) {
            $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_password = '{$_POST['post_password']}'");
            if ($result) {
                $location = $result[0]->post_name;
                do_action('init', $location, $_POST['post_password']); 
            } else {
                echo '<p>Invalid password</p>';
            }  
        }            
    ?>
```